# How to create multiple first in first out queues in celery?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, message-queue

I have a Django webservice running on one machine that submits jobs to a celery worker running on another machine.

Here is what my `models.py` looks like:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
```

This is what my celery systemd service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=celery daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=<user>
Group=<group>
WorkingDirectory=<path_to_working_directory>

ExecStart=celery multi start worker -A project --pidfile=<process_id_path> \
--concurrency=1 --logfile=<path_to_logfile> --loglevel=debug
ExecStop=celery multi stopwait worker -A project --pidfile=<process_id_path> \
--concurrency=1 --logfile=<path_to_logfile> --loglevel=debug
ExecReload=celery multi refresh worker -A project --pidfile=<process_id_path> \
--concurrency=1 --logfile=<path_to_logfile> --loglevel=debug

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Currently, I use a Django signal that creates a new queue every time a new department is added. However if I set the concurrency to 1 in my systemd file then the worker runs only one job at a time. And if i don't mention concurrency then it sometimes runs multiple jobs from the same queue parallelly. I want it to run multiple jobs parallelly, but at a given time only one from each queue should be running.

For example. Lets say there are 3 departments A,B,C. This creates 3 queues, one for each department, queueA, queueB, queueC. I want the worker to be concurrently running one job from queueA, one job from queueB and one job from ququeC. But it should never be running more than one job from a queue concurrently.

How do I achieve this using celery?